# How to get odoo model from javascript?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to do a widget to attach to the sysTrayMenu, I need to know on the on_click event, the current model of the view. I know that I can get it from the current browser url, but I wanted to know if is there a cleaner way to get it from the odoo js api.

For example if the user is in New quotation menu, I need to get sale.order

```
odoo.define('xx.systray', function (require) {
"use strict";

var config = require('web.config');
var SystrayMenu = require('web.SystrayMenu');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var ajax = require('web.ajax');


var xxMenu = Widget.extend({
    template:'solvo-support.helpMenu',
    events: {
        "click": "on_click",
    },
    on_click: function () {

//HERE I NEED TO GET THE CURRENT MODEL 
    },
});

SystrayMenu.Items.push(xxMenu);

});
```

Comment: `this.view.model` is an option if view exists in your context. If not, try with `this.field_manager.datarecord`. It has a lot of attributes of the current record, where you'll probably find the current model. Even just in `this.field_manager` you may find it.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember you can access the the model of the widget like this:

```js
         this.model // or self.model if you defined self (self = this)
```

all widget have this attribute it's string type contains the name of the model.

Comment: yes all fields have it but, but in mine is underfined, becouse I need the model of the current view, its a widget place it in the systray, is there any core module that store the model of the current load view?

Comment: What about action manager? I don't know if there is a way to access it directly from odoo variable may be?!!